# Why self-invoking closure to load Javascript FB SDK?

Tags: closures, facebook-javascript-sdk

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

2 questions:

1. Why is the code used to load the FB SDK inside a self-invoking closure?
2. What part of the code actually makes the SDK load asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is self calling so as to not polute the global namespace. It could have very eaisly have been written as follows:

```
function loadScript(d, s, id){
    //...
}
loadScript(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```

But then you've got an object called loadScript floating around at the global scope level, which would conflict with any other libraries that also have a variable or function called loadScript.

It's asynchronous because it inserts a script element into the DOM dynamically, which is an asynchronous operation. Take a look at this article for a deeper discussion, http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/

Also, that's not a closure, as there isn't a function inside the function. A closure is a function that maintains state of it's environment. In any event, that distinction isn't hugely important for this question.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clear explanation. I guess I should have said "self-invoking function"